# Confused in converting a ascii data conversion

Tags: java, string, hex, ascii

i am trying to understand the conversion logic of a ascii data string to BCD data representation in java

request some guidance.

my Ascii string

```
 data : 1000000011418819=11120000000000000001
```

HEX view of the input data

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 31 34 31 38 38 31 39  1000000011418819
00000010  3D 31 31 31 32 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  =111200000000000
00000020  30 30 30 30 31                                   00001
```

converted data (output result):

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000  37 10 00 00 00 11 41 88 19 D1 11 20 00 00 00 00  7.....Aˆ.Ñ. ....
00000010  00 00 00 10 31                                   ....1
```

what is way to convert the data of the shown in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have [packed BCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), The 37 at `7` at the start is not part of your original message.

What you need to do is take the lower 16 bits of each byte and combine them in pairs e.g. shift the first value by 4.

e.g.

```
InputStream in = 
OutputStream out = 
for(int i, j; (i = in.read()) >= 0 && (j = in.read()) > 0;) {
    out.write(((i & 0xF) << 4) + (j & 0xF));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you have packed BCD, and that the 37 is not part of the original number.  I will explain it a bit differently.

The ASCII representation you have has one byte per character; all the ascii numbers, in hex, are offsets from 30 hex, so '0' (ascii 0) is represented by a byte with a hex value of 30, '1' by 31, '2' by 32, etc.

Packed BCD puts two numbers in each byte by putting two of the lower significant hex digits into each byte, so the ascii "57", with hex values of 35 and 37, would be represented with a packed decimal byte of 57 hex.

The code given in another answer here looks essentially correct, but may be confusing if you don't understand the principle.  In order to convert, you take each pair of ascii digits, mask out or otherwise remove the higher-order 4 bits from their representative bytes, and combine the two lower-order 4-bit values into one 8-bit value.

Just to be complete, D1 is not part of BCD either -- it appears to represent the equals sign.